# resource color/cellback not found

Tags: xamarin.android, android-resources

so I was creating an android app via Xamarin.android that contains a customized listview following the steps in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/customizing-appearance#accessories. it worked well until I reached the step of the custom selector. when I added it I got the error in the title: resource color/cellback (aka com.companyname.app22:color/cellback) not found. in addition to "failed linking file resources" error. I tried restoring NuGet packages, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but it didn't work. I recreated the app but making the custom selector first but still got those errors. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource color/cellback` is the custom color name you need to define in the `Resources` --> `values` --> `colors.xml`:

[image]

Comment: @ranahd  Can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @ranahd What you did is upvote. I mean mark this answer: **click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer**. Thank you!

Comment: ohh i'm sorry, do I remove it?

Comment: @ranahd Don't remove it. It's fine. Thanks.